# É possível informar o tamanho do VARCHAR num NamedParameter?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, groovy

Estou trabalhando com um tuning de um banco de dados SQL Server.
Através da query abaixo, consigo ver como o banco executou algumas das minhas queries mais pesadas.

```sql
SELECT TOP 30 deqt.TEXT AS Query,
              last_execution_time
FROM   sys.dm_exec_query_stats deqs
       CROSS APPLY sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) deqt
       CROSS APPLY sys.Dm_exec_query_plan(deqs.plan_handle) deqp
WHERE  ( deqt.TEXT LIKE '%SELECT AV.ID,%'
         OR deqt.TEXT LIKE '%SELECT ''DEPARTMENT'' AS NODE,%'
         OR deqt.TEXT LIKE '%SELECT COUNT(P.COD) FROM _PEDIDOS P%WHERE P.CONCLUIDO = 1  AND P.COD_LOJA in ( @P0 ) AND P.STATUS_PARCEIRO =  @P1%' )
         --1 = 1
       AND deqt.TEXT NOT LIKE 'select top 30%'
       AND last_execution_time > Getdate() - 1
ORDER  BY 1
```

O problema segundo o DBA, é que o parâmetro de entrada da query era de um tipo diferente da coluna.
Por isso alterei o código Java para o seguinte:

```java
   final MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource()
    params.addValue('SKU', sku, Types.VARCHAR)
    params.addValue('ORGANIZATION_ID', organizationId, Types.BIGINT)

    List<AttributeValue> attributeValues = jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES, params, { ResultSet rs, int idx ->
```

Porém, chega VARCHAR(8000), e a coluna é 255. Existe como informar isso?
alguém sabe?

Comment: Esse seu código java está incompleto, a começar pelos ponto-e-vírgulas, mas o fato da última linha estar truncada também não ajuda. Fica mais fácil se você fornecer um [mcve].

Comment: o resto do código não é importante, até porque não vou postar todas as minhas classes de domínio aqui.
não tem ponto e vírgula porque uso Groovy.

o importante é o `MapSqlParameterSource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolvi fazendo um cast no SQL.

> WHERE field = CAST(:FIELD AS VARCHAR(255))